# Firestore: Getting documents sorted by a numeric field contained in the two sub-levels documents

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

My firm asked me to get all the documents from the root collection, `users`. They must be sorted according to the value of a numeric field, titled `amount`, present in a first sub-level document and also in a second sub-level document.

I don't know how to fulfill this aim easily with Firestore NoSQL queries. What would you recommend to me?

## Data structure

Here it is:

- users

  - user_1 (document to get and sort)
  - user_2 (document to get and sort)

Each of these two users is structured like this:

- collection_1

  - document_of_first_level

    - contains this field: `amount`
    - and contains also this collection: collection_2

      - document_of_second_level

        - contains this field: `amount`

---

So I should get a list containing `user_1` and `user_2`. This is a sorted list. It's sorted according to the two fields both named `amount`, which are contained under `user_1`, but also under `user_2`. These both fields are nested.

Comment: You can't do this in a single query.  You will likely have to read every single document in the subcollections and check for matches in the client.

Comment: Mh I think it's not compatible with the NoSQL philosophy. I will rather create a new field, in the users documents, containing the total amount. Then I will sort them according to the value of this new field. Btw, this field will be updated each time the user purchases something.

Comment: @DougStevenson what do you think about that?

Comment: Whatever you need to do to get your query done.

Comment: Um finally I will write several queries to sort, as you first recommended to me. I won't use the counter I was speaking about in my 2nd post since I'd use transactions, and transactions fail if the client is offline. It must not be the case in my application since money is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They must be sorted according to the value of a numeric field, titled amount, present in a first sub-level document and also in a second sub-level document.

As also @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, you cannot achieve this with Cloud Firestore. There is no way to get documents from a subcollection (level 1) and another subcollection (level 2) in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different subcollections in one go. Queries in Firestore are shallow, which means they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

So the most simple solution I can think of, would be to query the database twice, once to get the documents within subcollection (level 1) and second to get documents within subcollection (level 2) and then compare them client side.

The idea from your comment is a solution since adding a property under the level 1 document will allow you to query the database just once. In Firestore, you can simply chain multiple `where()` functions in a single query.